# SQL me da error en eclipse

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

No consigo escribir bien el siguiente código para ejecutar la sentencia SQL siguiente desde JAVA:

```java
sql = "UPDATE Trayectos_diario a, reservas b SET Trayectos_diario.libres = Trayectos_diario.libres + ? WHERE Trayectos_diario.id_trayectos_diario = reservas.id_trayectos_diario AND reservas.id_reserva = ? ";
            
pstmt_plazas_trayecto = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt_plazas_trayecto.setInt(1, n_billetes);
pstmt_plazas_trayecto.setInt(2, id_reserva);
pstmt_plazas_trayecto.executeUpdate();
```

La intención es que, teniendo el `ID_RESERVA` de la tabla `reserva`, modificar el registro `libres` de la tabla `Trayectos_diario`. Estas tablas están referenciadas por el campo `ID_TRAYECTO_DIARIO` que existe en ambas.

Entiendo que el error de Oracle es que no detecta el SET o está mal definido:

> ORA-00971: missing SET keyword

Comment: En Oracle sólo puedes actualizar una tabla a la vez.

Answer (score 0):

Tu sintaxis del UPDATE es incorrecta. No puedes poner dos tablas de esa manera. En este caso, podrías usar un operador IN. Dejo únicamente el código SQL para que quede más legible.

```
UPDATE Trayectos_diario 
SET libres = libres + ? 
WHERE id_trayectos_diario IN (SELECT r.id_trayectos_diario 
                              FROM reservas r 
                              WHERE r.id_reserva = ?);
```